# Wordpress links leads me to wamp server configuration page (Localhost)

Tags: wordpress, localhost, hyperlink

i have online Wordpress blog, now i copied my blog to localhost to change the design.
I replaced http://mydomain to http://localhost (in database & Wordpress configuration) .

The blog is working great in my localhost, but when i click on some category or post link it leads me to wamp page, there's something that i missing, any idea what can be the problem? by the way the a href links have right structure.

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 6):

Possibly your `.htaccess` file inside the `www/wordpress` folder has a wrong `RewriteBase` configuration

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

WAMP returns a 404 for completely non-existent links for me. Not sure why you're getting the homepage-are you using normal permalinks? (http://www.myblog.com/?p=123)

Typically with wamp you're going to have to install your blog in a subdirectory-localhost/blog/ or something like that. Using just the main directory can cause problems (especially if you want an easy place to launch phpmyadmin or switch from project to project!).

Maybe you already installed it in a subdirectory and so the links just point to root-which is where the wamp homepage sits.

Comment: the links point to right place , my wordpress url is localhost/wp , and the links are localhost/wp/category/post-name

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have placed the absolute URL in your Wordpress Template? If not, check the wp-options Table in your database if there is the old URL in it.

Then you have to clear your cache if you have installed a Cache Plugin in Wordpress.

Image links are still linking to the old URI, if you also would redirect these, then you have to replace your old url with your current URI in the wp-posts table.